# Lexical or preprocessor issue 'SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h' file not found

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I have no problem building my project but when i tried to Archive it, i am getting the following error

```
Lexical or preprocessor issue 'SDWebImage/UIImageView+WebCache.h' file not found
```

This error happens only when i try Archive the app.

I am using iOS5.1, Please let me know how to fix this issue

Comment: @H2CO3: thanks i have corrected

Comment: @userXXXX me too (in the title).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Are you making sure to include the SDWebImage search paths in both debug and release targets? If it is just in debug, that would explain why it is only not working when you archive.

Image from SDWebImage Github:

https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage